# How to set keyboard type inside an alert

Tags: swift, keyboard, uialertcontroller

I have the following code which uses an alert to gather an email address from the user.  I'd like to specify the keyboard type but haven't been able to figure out how to do that inside an alert.  Is anyone able to help show how to set `.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress`?

```
var userInput: String = ""
let prompt = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: "Enter your email address", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
    userInput = prompt.textFields![0].text
    if (userInput!.isEmpty) {
        return
    }
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    print(action)
}
prompt.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
prompt.addAction(okAction)
prompt.addAction(cancelAction)
self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(prompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch this with the addTextfield line. Basically this is where you do the configuration for your textfield as it implies.

```
prompt.addTextField { (textfield) in
   textfield.keyboardType = .emailAddress
}
```